# How to send a variable's value only once when a push button is released?

Tags: c++, c, button, arduino

So I have a push button that changes a variable value, which controls a motor's strength, when pressed. It goes through a loop back and forth and stops when I release it.

The problem is that whenever the value changes it's being sent to the motor. I want the value to change when I press the button (without sending it to the motor) and when I'll release the button the value will be sent once to the motor (instead of the motor will change its strength very fast all the time and shake).

Here's what I have:

```
increment = 1;
        void update() {
            if (millis() - last_update > 300) {
                last_update = millis();
                strength += increment;
                analogWrite(LAUNCHER_PIN, strength);
                Serial.print("Canon strength: ");
                Serial.print(strength);
                if (strength <= CANON_MIN || strength >= CANON_MAX) increment = -increment;
            }
        }
if (!digitalRead(MOTOR_BTN_PIN)) update();
```

Comment: Detect the *transition* of the button by remembering its previous state.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: I used an interrupt that runs a function whenever the button is released.
Inside that function I putted the ```analogWrite(LAUNCHER_PIN, strength)```

Comment: Attach _interrupt_ on push button and detect transition changes form unpressed state to pressed down state and vice versa.

Comment: I want that only when I release the button the motor will get the strength value once (the final value).

On my code it sends the value every 300ms so the motor's strength changes with my press.

Answer (score 2):

This is could easily be solved with a simple *state machine*.

You could have two states: `NORMAL`, `BUTTON_DOWN`.

Normally you should be in the `NORMAL` state, and the `loop` function checks if the button is pressed or not. If the button is pressed and you're in state `NORMAL`, then you set the state to `BUTTON_DOWN` and do whatever other processing you need to do when the button is pressed.

If the button is not pressed, and the current state is `BUTTON_DOWN` you know that the button have been released and you go back to the `NORMAL` state and do the button-release processing that needs to be done.

Since you only have two states, you could represent that as a single `bool` variables, where (for example) `false` means `NORMAL` and `true` means `BUTTON_DOWN`.

In ***pseudo*** code it could be something like

```
void loop()
{
    if (state == NORMAL)
    {
        // Do normal processing

        if (is_button_pressed())
        {
            // Do buttown-down processing

            state = BUTTON_DOWN;
        }
    }
    else if (state == BUTTON_DOWN)
    {
        if (!is_button_pressed())
        {
            // Do button-release processing

            state = NORMAL;
        }
    }
}
```

---

By adding a third state, `BUTTON_DEBOUNCE`, you could easily handle debounce of the button.

When in state `NORMAL` and you detect the button being pressed, you enter the `BUTTON_DEBOUNCE` state. If you have been in the `BUTTON_DEBOUNCE` state for a certain amount of time (say a few milliseconds) and the button is still pressed then you enter the `BUTTON_PRESSED` state and to the button-pressed processing.

If after the short time the button is not pressed, you go back to the `NORMAL` state.

If you add a third state like this, then you can no longer have a simple `bool` variable representing the state. An enumeration and a variable of that enumeration type might be a better choice then.

Comment: very simple solution! Alongside with a external interrupt, this would be very responsive

Answer (score 1):

You can use flag to solve this issue,create a flag variable **boolean** and set it **true** and **false** when event occurs and only pass the value when flag is true

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need your main process to continue doing stuff while you press buttons, then you can do something like:

```
while (!digitalRead(MOTOR_BTN_PIN))
{
    if (digitalRead(MOTOR_BTN_PIN))
        update();
}
```

When you press the button you get trapped in the while, and when you finally let go `update()` gets called (once).

Comment: Although this does work, it's not advised as it locks your system in a loop, so if you need to keep track of other stuff or to have control of other outputs, this would make it harder for you to control... Possibly making so that you duplicate your remaining code to occur inside and outside of your infinite loop

Comment: @BrenoTeodoro True, if you need something to be running regularly in your main loop, then a solution like the one proposed by SomeProgrammerDude is the correct one. The only benefit of this one, is that it takes a fraction of the code and in many situations is "good enough".

Comment: Agreed, your code would suffice for most applications, and would only present the issue raised in a fraction of them. It also has the advantage of occupying very little space in memory. It's an effective way of resolving the issue, just thought I'd point out this minor issue, should KD Technology face it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the "edge" of the signal when it's going down.

You can think of a buttons signal as a square. When the button is not pressed there is nothing, when you press it, the voltage flows, so it looks like this (this image illustrates a system where you connect your button in pulldown):

[image]

So, in total, there are four states of a given digital signal:

1. There is *nothing* (this can either be a **LOW** or a **HIGH**, depending on your connection; in the example I brought, the *nothing* relates to a **HIGH** signal, as I turned on the built-in PULLUP resistor of the arduino digital pin);
2. There is a *signal* (which is always the inverse of point **1**;
3. There is a ramp from *nothing* to *signal*;
4. There is a ramp from *signal* to *nothing*

In your case, you'll make use of point **4**, as this is the state where the button is no longer pressed, and the microcontroller stops receiving signal.

Try this:

```
#define btnPin 2

uint8_t btn_prev;

void setup() {
  pinMode(btnPin, INPUT_PULLUP);

  // here the previous button signal is set to HIGH, as we enabled the pullup
  btn_prev = digitalRead(btnPin);
}

void loop() {
 //for each iteration we read the button singal
 uint8_t btn = digitalRead(btnPin);

 // we call your update function when the button was low and is now high: a.k.a. falling edge
 if (btn == LOW && btn_prev == HIGH)
  {
    update();
  }

  // at last, we update the previous state of the button, so that we can check again for a change in the next iteration
  btn_prev = digitalRead(btnPin);
}
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: `btn_prev = digitalRead(btnPin);` should probably be `btn_prev = btn` instead, otherwise you risk that the button state changes between the top and bottom of the loop. Which would mean that `btn` reads `LOW` at the top, button is pressed during the `if`, `btn_prev` reads `HIGH` at the bottom, and then in the next loop `btn` is also read as `HIGH` - and now you just lost a button press. If you instead limit it to a single read per loop, and just remember the last logic value, then the race condition goes away.

Comment: The ATmega328P, present in the most common arduino Uno and Nano boards, can perform roughly 8 million instructions a second, so your code would have to be very heavy to have this situation occur. In the same scenario, with your suggestion applied, if I read the value while pressing, release and press again before the loop has finished, you've just lost a button press. The way I proposed is intended to lessen the odds of this happening, as the last & the fist actions are to read and compare the values. To eliminate the issue altogether, we should make use of External Interrupts.